# Stream S3 CSV data conditionally to Kinesis

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift

My CSV file stored in an Amazon S3 bucket has `datapresent flag=true/false`.

- If `flag=false`: data from other S3 bucket should be copied to Redshift table
- Else: Copy from first S3 bucket based on timestamp in file

How to achieve this?

Comment: What is the trigger for this whole process? That is, what should activate this decision logic? Is it the creation of a file? What have you tried so far?

Comment: File x in s3 bucket will have column flag. If it is set to false, same file with edited contents from other s3 bucket should be read.

Comment: But what STARTS this whole process? Is it when that file is uploaded to S3? Should that trigger the steps you've listed above?

Comment: Seems that you have designed some strange data flow / architecture process without thinking about how it will be done - then asked us here how to make your plan work. if you describe your overall requirement in a bit more detail it may help.

Comment: File with edited contents dropped to S3 trigger the process